# How to use NLog InternalLogger's method to write to NLog's internal log file

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using NLog for logging in my library and I have created custom NLog Target to upload log entries to Azure Data Explorer. However, in the event that exception is encountered when uploading logs to Azure Data Explorer, I want to log an error message in my local log files.

However, I cannot use NLog's File Target for this error logging because by calling NLog's logging API again my custom Target will be invoked again, thus leading to infinite loop.

Thus, I want to use NLog's InternalLogger, which logs to NLog's internal log file, to log the upload error. However, when I used the below InternalLogger method it does not log to the internal log file.

```
InternalLogger.Error(e, msg);
```

The InternalLogger class is documented [here](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/T_NLog_Common_InternalLogger.htm)

I am wondering if I am missing a configuration step or it is impossible to log to the NLog's internal log file?

Comment: Have you activated the InternalLogger? You need to assign `InternalLogger.LogLevel` (works as MinLevel) and also assign a filename to `InternalLogger.LogFile`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a tutorial [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging)

In summary:

Enable the internal log, it's disabled by default

### In config (nlog.config)

```xml
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
```

### From code

Or from code:

```cs
// set internal log level
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;

// enable internal logging to a file
InternalLogger.LogFile = "c:\\log.txt";
```